# two column enumeration in beamer slide

Tags: beamer, multicol

I have tried to obtain two column choices in beamer using the code below:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[height=16mm]{Rochester}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white!20}
%\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{Picture2.png}\vspace{220pt}}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.85\textwidth,-1cm)
\Huge\textcolor{white}{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{Picture2.jpg}\vspace{220pt}}
\end{textblock*}}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white!20}
\title{KCET CRASH COURSE}
\subtitle{Quadratic Equations}
\author{G Ekaveera}

%\usetheme{lucid}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
    \frame {
        \titlepage
    }
    \frame {
        \frametitle{Definition }

        An equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$ where $a \ne 0$

        and $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$
    }
    \frame{
        \frametitle{Quadratic Formula}
        %\framesubtitle{A factor which converts LHS in to Exact Differential }
        The roots are given by $$\alpha=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

        and $$\beta=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

        Where $D=b^2-4ac$ is called Discriminant of the Quadratic
        }
        \frame{
        \frametitle{Relation between roots and coefficients}

        \framesubtitle{Sum and Product of the roots}
        $$\alpha+\beta=\frac{-b}{a}$$

            $$\alpha \times \beta=\frac{c}{a}$$

        }

        %By product rule of differentiation we get:

        %$$R(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+yR'(x)=Q(x)R(x) -(3)$$

    \frame {
    \frametitle{Nature of the roots}
    If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item If $D > 0$ roots are real and distinct
        \item If $D=0$ roots are real and equal
        \item if $D <0$ roots are complex conjugates
        \item D is discriminant
    \end{enumerate}
}
\end{document}
```

But I get choices in single column. How to get choices in two column?

Comment: I'm not sure which "choices" your are talking about. Do you want the enumeration in two columns?

Comment: Yes ofcourse thats what i asked

Comment: off-topic: don't use `$$....$$` for equations: [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: off-topic: `\begin{frame}{my frametitle}...\end{frame}` is much more readable...

Comment: ya i used double dollar for centered alignment of equation

Comment: Yes i need first two choices in one row and next two choices in 2nd row

Answer (score 4):

You could split the `enumeration` into two parts:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{textpos}

\usetheme[height=16mm]{Rochester}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{%
    \begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.85\textwidth,-1cm)
        \Huge\textcolor{white}{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{example-image}\vspace{220pt}}
    \end{textblock*}
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white!20}

\title{KCET CRASH COURSE}
\subtitle{Quadratic Equations}
\author{G Ekaveera}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Nature of the roots}
    If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item If $D > 0$ roots are real and distinct
                \item If $D=0$ roots are real and equal
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \addtocounter{enumi}{2}
                \item if $D <0$ roots are complex conjugates
                \item D is discriminant
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent. will the same applicable if i use \begin  {choices}?

Comment: @Ekaveera I don't know which package you use or how you define `\begin{choices}`, so I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks what do you mean by enumi

Comment: @Ekaveera That's the name of the counter for the numeration of the items